# Positioning absolute image element over section

Tags: css

I am trying to create a floating div that contains a background image that fits between 2 different sections of the page. I have set the z index of the item, but the section below keeps cutting the image off. The div in question with the image is .genie-image and the section that is cutting it off is white__explainer--text. How could I fix this to get this look:

[image: Wanted look]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');

*::before,
*,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container-svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

.background-image {
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556761175-4b46a572b786?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80');
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.genie-image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Simon-Bailey.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 5%;

  z-index: 9000;
}

#white__explainer--text {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.seperator {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 25px;
}

.left__column {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right__column {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}

.title {
  color: #f58220;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-svg">
      <div class="background-image"></div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path
          d="
           M 0,50
           C 150,150 300,0 500,100 
           L 500,00 
           L 0,0 
           Z"
          style="stroke: none; fill: lightgrey"
        ></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="genie-image"></div>
    </div>
    <section id="white__explainer--text">
      <div class="seperator">
        <div class="left__column">
          <div>
            <div class="title">LOREM IPSUM</div>
            <div class="paragraph">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt
              optio ea, tempore voluptatum aspernatur quam vitae eius.
              Dignissimos corporis ex, consequuntur officia, nihil atque ducimus
              reprehenderit temporibus quod commodi nobis!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right__column">
          Lorem <br />
          ipsum dolor <br />
          sit amet, consectetur <br />
          adipisicing, <br />
          sed do
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
  <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</html>
```

Comment: You should remove the 'overflow:hidden' on the container-svg and put it on the body if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in full page with snippet. I think it would need more improvement to make it more flexible, specialy for small media. But I guess you could do that

I simply took the div image out of your div which contains the banner and add a padding-top: 250px on your class left__column

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');

*::before,
*,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container-svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

.background-image {
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556761175-4b46a572b786?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80');
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.genie-image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Simon-Bailey.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 5%;

  z-index: 9000;
}

#white__explainer--text {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.seperator {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 25px;
}

.left__column {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 250px; /* this has been added */
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right__column {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}

.title {
  color: #f58220;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-svg">
      <div class="background-image"></div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path
          d="
           M 0,50
           C 150,150 300,0 500,100 
           L 500,00 
           L 0,0 
           Z"
          style="stroke: none; fill: lightgrey"
        ></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="genie-image"></div>
    <section id="white__explainer--text">
      <div class="seperator">
        <div class="left__column">
          <div>
            <div class="title">LOREM IPSUM</div>
            <div class="paragraph">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt
              optio ea, tempore voluptatum aspernatur quam vitae eius.
              Dignissimos corporis ex, consequuntur officia, nihil atque ducimus
              reprehenderit temporibus quod commodi nobis!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right__column">
          Lorem <br />
          ipsum dolor <br />
          sit amet, consectetur <br />
          adipisicing, <br />
          sed do
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
  <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</html>
```

OR you keep the image into your container, and then you remove the overflow from your container (but the problem would be that your other elements may go out of the div too...

I also add a padding-top:250px on your class left__column

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');

*::before,
*,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container-svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/ 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

.background-image {
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556761175-4b46a572b786?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80');
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.genie-image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Simon-Bailey.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;

  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 5%;

  z-index: 9000;
}

#white__explainer--text {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.seperator {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 25px;
}

.left__column {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 250px; /* this has been added */
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right__column {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}

.title {
  color: #f58220;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-svg">
      <div class="background-image"></div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path
          d="
           M 0,50
           C 150,150 300,0 500,100 
           L 500,00 
           L 0,0 
           Z"
          style="stroke: none; fill: lightgrey"
        ></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="genie-image"></div>
    </div>
    
    <section id="white__explainer--text">
      <div class="seperator">
        <div class="left__column">
          <div>
            <div class="title">LOREM IPSUM</div>
            <div class="paragraph">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt
              optio ea, tempore voluptatum aspernatur quam vitae eius.
              Dignissimos corporis ex, consequuntur officia, nihil atque ducimus
              reprehenderit temporibus quod commodi nobis!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right__column">
          Lorem <br />
          ipsum dolor <br />
          sit amet, consectetur <br />
          adipisicing, <br />
          sed do
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
  <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</html>
```